# Read multi-index on the columns from csv file

Tags: csv, pandas, multi-index

I have a .csv file that looks like this:

```
Male, Male, Male, Female, Female
R, R, L, R, R
.86, .67, .88, .78, .81
```

I want to read that into a df, so that I have:

```
    Male        Female
    R       L   R
0   .86 .67 .88 .78 .81
```

I did:

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=[0,1])
```

But `headers` does not cut it. Which results in

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [(Male, R), (Male, R), (Male, L), (Female, R), (Female, R)]
Index: []
```

Yet, the docs on headers says:

```
(...)Can be a list of integers that specify row
locations for a multi-index on the columns E.g. [0,1,3]
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I possibly make it work?

Answer (score 32):

I think the problem is that you have duplicated columns: two ( Female, R).

Not sure whether it's a bug or the duplicated columns are unacceptable. Here's a workaround for you:

### First read the csv with tupleize_cols=True

```
In [61]: df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=[0, 1], skipinitialspace=True, tupleize_cols=True)

In [62]: df
Out[62]: 
   (Male, R)  (Male, R)  (Male, L)  (Female, R)  (Female, R)
0       0.67       0.67       0.88         0.81         0.81

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```

### Then convert the type of the column from Index to MultiIndex

```
In [63]: df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(df.columns)

In [64]: df
Out[64]: 
   Male              Female      
      R     R     L       R     R
0  0.67  0.67  0.88    0.81  0.81

[1 rows x 5 columns]
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the suggestion. At first sight, it seems legit, but  values got messed up someway, take a look at our initial ones `.86, .67, .88, .78, .81`

Comment: Sorry for the misleading. Seems it's another bug to fix. Will update this post while I find another way to achieve your goal

Comment: C:\Python\Python36_64b\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py:813: FutureWarning: The 'tupleize_cols' argument has been deprecated and will be removed in a future version. Column tuples will then always be converted to MultiIndex.


  self.options, self.engine = self._clean_options(options, engine)

Answer (score 27):

As of version 0.21 of pandas, MultiIndexes are created by default so `df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=[0,1])` should do the job.