# how to parse merge colume to dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv, pivot

have a CSV that produces a Excel sheet in the following format
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRspW.png)
When inform dataframe, it looks like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A7lxN.png)
What I would like to Do is, Group country name in row together and convert to colume to columns. So, the final dataframe should look like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XEhnB.png)
I have tried df.pivot() but it doesn't give the required format

I have tried df.pivot() but it doesn't give the required format

Comment: [why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors)

Comment: You should maybe start by reading in the CSV data as a DF with multi-index columns since that is your Excel format. See [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21318865). You will always get better responses to SO questions by providing reproducible data instead of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this after read your file like dataframe (df):

```
df.columns = list(pd.DataFrame(df.columns).replace(
    'Unnamed\.?\d?', np.nan, regex=True).ffill(limit=1)[0])
df = df.set_index(['Product SKU', 'Product Name'])
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.columns, df.iloc[0].values])
df = df.iloc[1:]
df = pd.DataFrame(df.stack(level=0).to_records())
```

Comment: Please, upvote my answer and mark it like a solution